# Howto to configure gradle DependencyReport(-task) to output only for one task releaseApk

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, report, task

How to configure the "gradle [DependencyReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask.html)"-task of the [project-report plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_reports_plugin.html) for android so that it only contains dependencies 
for one task **"_releaseApk"** but **not for all tasks** like
releaseCompile, debugCompile, debugApk, ...

The result should be similar to the output of

```
gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration _releaseApk
```

I have this  app/build.gradle

```
// app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'project-report'
android {...}
dependencies {
    // dependencies to be listed by DependencyReport
    compile '...'
}

// these config-s do not work with gradle-2.14
// DependencyReport.configurations ["_releaseApk"]
// reports.configurations ["_releaseApk"]
```

and call

```
gradle app:DependencyReport
```

the generated app/build/reports/project/dependencies.txt contains
dependencies for all tasks like
releaseApk, releaseCompile, debugCompile, debugApk, ...

I only want dependencies for releaseApk